# mariadb c-connector bind / execute mess up memory allocation

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-connector-c

i'm using mariadb c-connector with prepare, bind and execute. it works usualy. but one case end up in "corrupted unsorted chunks" and core dumping when freeing bind buffer. i suggest the whole malloc organisation is messed up after calling mysql_stmt_execute(). my test's [MysqlDynamic.c](http://www.ois-net.org/download/temp/) show:

- the problem only is connected to x509cert variable bound by bnd[9]
- freeing memory only fails if bnd[9].is_null = 0, if is_null execute end normally
- freeing memory (using FreeStmt()) after bind and before execute end normally
- print of bnd[9].buffer before execute show (void*) is connected to the correct string buffer
- same behavior for setting bnd[9].buffer_length to STMT_INDICATOR_NTS or strlen()
- other similar bindings (picture, bnd[10]) do not lead to corrupted memory and core dump.

i defined a c structure test for test data in my test program [MysqlDynamic.c](http://www.ois-net.org/download/temp/) which is bound in MYSQL_BIND structure.

bindings for x509cert (string buffer) see bindInsTest():

```
    bnd[9].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    bnd[9].buffer_length = STMT_INDICATOR_NTS;
    bnd[9].is_null = &para->x509certI;
    bnd[9].buffer = (void*) para->x509cert;
```

please get the details out of source file [MysqlDynamic.c](http://www.ois-net.org/download/temp/). please adapt defines in the source to your environment, verify content, and run it. you will find compile info in source code. `MysqlDynymic -c` will create the table. `MysqlDynamic -i` will insert 3 records each run. And 'MysqlDynamic -d` drop the the table again.

MysqlDynamic -vc show:

```
session set autocommit to <0>
connection id: 175
mariadb server ver:<100408>, client ver:<100408>
connected on localhost to db test by testA
>> if program get stuck - table is locked
table t_test created
mysql connection closed
pgm ended normaly
```

MysqlDynamic -i show

```
ins2: BufPara <92> name<master> stamp<> epoch<1651313806000>
cert is cert<(nil)> buf<(nil)> null<1>
picure is pic<0x5596a0f0c220> buf<0x5596a0f0c220> null<0> length<172>
ins1: BufPara <91> name<> stamp<2020-04-30> epoch<1650707701123>
cert is cert<0x5596a0f181d0> buf<0x5596a0f181d0> null<0>
picure is pic<(nil)> buf<(nil)> null<1> length<0>
ins0: BufPara <90> name<gugus> stamp<1988-10-12T18:43:36> epoch<922337203685477580>
cert is cert<(nil)> buf<(nil)> null<1>
picure is pic<(nil)> buf<(nil)> null<1> length<0>
free(): corrupted unsorted chunks
Aborted (core dumped)
```

checking t_test table content show all records are inserted as expected.
you can disable loading of x509cert and/or picture by commenting out the defines line 57/58. the program than end normally. you also can comment out line 208. the buffers are then indicated as NULL.

Questions:

- is there a generic coding mistake in the program causing this behavior?
- can you run the program in your environment without core dumping? i'm currently using version 10.04.08.

any improvment in code will be welcome.

Comment: 10.4.8 was 2.5 years ago. Have you tried a newer version?

Comment: thank you - good point. i migrated to 10.7.3 and i tried it.

Comment: A short code snippet that exactly reproduces the problem would be much more helpful. With around 650 lines of code, true to the motto "It was hard to write, so it should be hard to read" don't necessarily expect an answer.